# TSQL SELECT TOP(if flag=true then Limit, ELSE unlimited)

Tags: t-sql

I have a stored procedure in which, if an input parameter flag is set I want to limit number of records returned. If flag is false I want the SELECT statement to return unlimited number of records. I want to accomplish this in the most cost-effective way possible. Some thing like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @flagLimit THEN TOP(@limit) 
                 ELSE [unlimited] 
FROM myTable...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use percent then

```
SELECT TOP(@limit)PERCENT
```

And you could just pass 100 for all

if you have to pass a number then you could pass a 0 for 100 percent and anything different calculate a percent based on count(*) but then you have to run the base query twice

Comment: this answer works well for me as using a percent is not a problem. Is this as efficient in terms of execution as jpw's method above?

Comment: I just don't know.  You should test them both.

Comment: Thanks @Frisbee, this method seems to work well without slowing down my original query and without having to duplicate all the query text in two separate SELECT statements.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe an `if` statement would work? You can conditionally choose different statements to execute depending on whether the flag is set. Something like this:

```
if @flaglimit is not null
select top (@limit) * from myTable
else
select * from myTable
```

Comment: I have a fairly lengthy & complex query after the Select statement. If I use your method, do I have to duplicate the exact code on both Select statements. If not, I would probably accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

IF @limit IS NULL

SELECT @limit = COUNT(1) FROM myTable

SELECT TOP(@limit) FROM myTable